# how to solve Socket.io Client side wait an emit message upto complete running emit?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, eventemitter

I am newbie in socket.io technology. I am trying to call & synchronously auto play an audio list which emitted by other people. It perfect when single emit trigger. When multiple emitting then it play asynchronously. But I want to call it **synchronously**, either it will mess up. Didn't understand where should I put the callback

> **Server side**

```
  socket.on('sound-broadcast', function (message) {

        io.emit('sound-emit', message);

  });
```

> **Client Side**

```
     socket.on('connect', function () {
        window.autoPlay = true;
               socket.on('sound-emit', function (data) {

                    var counter = 1; 

                    data.text.forEach(function(element) {
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            var audio = main_url+element+'.wav';
                            var sound = new Howl({
                                src: [audio]
                            });
                                sound.play();
                                console.log("Counter " +counter);

                            }, counter*2000);
                        counter ++;

                    });

               }); 

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('disconnected');
    });

});
```

> **Sample Data**
>   { type: 'voice',
>     text: [ 'token_number', 0, 36, 'counter_number', 75 ] }

**Sample Data** text key value is the name of audio file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure that understood you right, but if you'd like to play the list only once per click, you can implement this behaviour in two ways:
First one, create flag, which shows the playing status for current user.

```
 // On top of your file
 let playing = false;
 socket.on('connect', function () {
    window.autoPlay = true;

    socket.on('sound-emit', async (data) => {
       // check if player already playing the music
       if (playing) {
         return;
       }

       // Player not playing, so change status for further invocations prevent
       playing = true;

       let counter = 1;

       for (let elem of data.text) {
         await new Promise(resolve => {
           setTimeout(function () {
              const audio = main_url + element + '.wav';
              const sound = new Howl({
                src: [audio],
                onend: function () {
                  console.log('Finished!');
                  counter += 1;
                  resolve();
                },
            });
            sound.play();
          }, counter * 2000);
      });
    }
  })
});
```

Or with queue, where you save play action on each click and then check this queue.

Comment: without async function how it possible to use await? By the way it will play automatically